# How to make TypeScript understand that a class can be treated as a string?

Tags: typescript

I have a class with a `.toString()` method:

```js
class StringableItem {
    text: string

    constructor(str: string) {
        this.text = str
    }

    toString() {
        return this.text
    }
}

const foo = new StringableItem('hey')
```

In some contexts, for example template strings, TS understands that an instance of this class can be coerced into a string, and there is no error:

```js
const alpha: string = `${foo}`
const bravo = `${foo}`
```

But if I try to assign the instance to some var that must be a string, then I see the TypeScript error `Type 'StringableItem' is not assignable to type 'string'`:

```js
let charlie: string = ''
charlie = foo // Type 'StringableItem' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

How can I type this class so that TS knows it can be treated as a string in most/all contexts where a string is needed?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuAnAlgOwOZgEYgKYEl5cBbaAbwChproiAPeALmgiTXQqpuAHtVXEAV2DweiABQDmA9gEpyXGjXgALZBAB09eNAC8LJIugBfTktEIUGcfMpKliXPEGJUtNZu1HTpir346AGY8PHrQqLgA7nBsGNh4hCTiAOQquACeybKcAPQ50AByobiIiGLQkWlughC4ACYVyKpo0GC0JAAO4EQGVhz+rK0gHSpg0rHoYQAGACRkwTzGU358g1iIYABuofqz8yFLufkAKukduNAlZYgVVa1QyOio7LShEDzETmoY7mA6xDUdFgLm0ZBgKHgdMBRogQMhcOM+mFksk-DC4Rd9AtoHloKdztBkpZ2PECERiMloOpwjwdJAII9UKTXrQzhdkmD0KigA)

Comment: I don't get it... it's *not* a `string`, it can just be coerced into one.  If you write `charlie.toUpperCase()` you get a runtime error.  That doesn't look like "most/all contexts where a string is needed" to me.  Why not just write `charlie = String(foo)` instead of pretending that `foo` is a `string`?

Comment: It cannot be treated as a string in *most* contexts. Literally *any* Javascript object can be used inside of a template literal. Your class is not special in this regard. Your class is no more string-like than any random class written by anyone else.

Comment: I'm starting to see where my confusion comes from. In my actual use case, both `string` and an interface are accepted:

`interface Delta { }; const echo: string | Delta = foo /* TS allows this */`

It seems that TS considered my class instance to be comparable to the interface (though I'm not sure why because they appear unrelated) and I misinterpreted why TS was accepting it.